# How to avoid going back to a previous section tagged with an HTML id attribute and go to a previous website instead?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom

I have a single page website with multiple sections (Home, Services, Portfolio, Contact). I'm using the `id` attribute to point to each section.

How do I avoid the browser to store that `#home` or whichever sections I navigate through in the history and take me just to the previous website?

Is there any way to achieve it?

What I've search around is that this is related to website state. So, each click over any section updates the website state in the URL by adding `#` and the name of the `id`. The state can be changed by using `onhashchange` function in JavaScript. I don't know exactly how to use it or if another approach can be implemented.

Comment: Window.history.replacestate() might help or using a plugin to navigate through the sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as Aditya Thakur has pointed. You can use ***window.history.replaceState()***

Here is an example code:

```
<a href="#home" onclick="handleLink(event, this)">Home</a>
```

And the handleLink function:

```
function handleLink(event, element) {
    event.preventDefault();

    window.history.replaceState(null, "Title", element.href);
  }
```

The replaceState will not add a new entry to your browser history. So, when you click in the back button on your browser you'll return to the previous page.

Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method

Hope it can help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works perfect. Imma read a bit more about it to fully understand how can I modify the behavior.